# Failed to execute script due to unhandled exception: input(): lost sys.stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero ejecutar un script que logré transformar a .exe con pyinstaller y cuando lo ejecuto en mi computadora o en otra
me lanza el siguiente error:

> Failed to execute script "nombre_del_script" due to unhandled exception: input(): lost sys.stdin

Este es el código fuente del programa:

```
print("Fiesta de mi amigo, invitados y lo que hay que llevar")
propietario = raw_input("Introduzca el nombre del organizador de la fiesta: ")


invitados = ["Otro amigo", "Amigo", "mi amigo, "mi otro amigo", "otro amigo más",] #Modifique los nombres de la lista por obvias razónes

llevarse = ["Gaseosas", "Choris", "Algo para picar", "Choris secos"]

if propietario=="El nombre de mi amigo":
    print("Permiso concedido para acceder a la lista de la fiesta")
    for invitado in invitados:
        print(invitados)

    for llevar in llevarse:
        print(llevarse)
        print("Fin del programa ;)")
else:
    print("Acceso denegado")

while propietario=='':
    print("Acceso denegado, introduzca el nombre del usuario")
```

He utilizado `pyinstaller` así:

> pyinstaller --clean --onefile --windowed el_nombre_del_archivo.py

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: version de python? por el `print()` parece que usas python 3 pero en este no existe `raw_input()`

Comment: El parametro --windowed, a pesar de su nombre, hace que el script se ejecute sin mostrar la consola. Probablemente sea esa la causa del error. Y viendo el diseño de tu programa, creo que lo que quieres es un programa que muestre la consola.

Comment: Christian es la versión 3.6.0

Comment: Ok Dante, lo intentaré

Comment: Dante me funcionó. Gracias a todos. Pero se me generó otro problema, al ejecutar el script y poner el nombre de mi amigo o otro nombre se me cierra el programa automáticamente. ¿Alguna solución para eso?